# Use PostGIS columns transparently in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgis

I have a PostgreSQL table which contains, among many other columns, a spatial column `point`. This spatial column should give their contents in geoJson-Format.

A normal SQL should look like this:

```sql
select column1, column2, column3, ST_AsGeoJSON(point) from table;
```

And a writeback:

```sql
update table set column1 = 'abc', column2 = 'def', column3 = 'ghi', 
  point = ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ ... geojson ... }') 
  where id = ??;
```

I know there is an extension for hibernate called hibernate-spatial. But this extension is for postgis 1.5 which can read geoJson, but not parse and write back geoJson to PostgreSQL. Another disadvantage: Spatial operations (like conversions) are done on server-side, not on database-side.

Is there any possibility to inject a sql-function to a query like this:

```java
EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
myModel selected = em.find(myModel.class, 1);
```

In myModel the used column for the geometry should be a `String` or a inherited type of String which represents a geoJson.

I found Hibernate Dialects but it seems they work only on HQL (or JPL). I would like to use this geojson transparently - not in combination with HQL (where I forced to write SQL in code, what I don't want).

It is also possible to use [`setCustomWrite`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/mapping/Column.html#setCustomWrite(java.lang.String)) and [setCustomRead](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/mapping/Column.html#setCustomRead(java.lang.String)) but I didn't find any examples how to use them.

To prevent answers why I would like to leave the type in postgis-geometry - It should be left in this type because of other spatial-related operations on db-side.

Comment: It seems this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207207/automatically-apply-field-conversion-function-in-hibernate) points to close problem.

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem? I have a similar one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437375/how-to-map-postgis-geometry-column-as-wkt-with-nhibernate-not-using-nhibernate-s

Answer (score 0):

Dialect is for hibernate you just have to use the postgres driver...